# Using Lists to store data from a BufferedReader file

Tags: c#, list, csv, store, bufferedreader

I've been trying to use lists to store data from a .csv file, but since I'm new to using lists, I can't seem to be able to get it to work.  I've searched many tutorials but none of them are working for me. I must be missing something.  Here's what I have so far:

```
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;

        String fileInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                "Please enter the path of the CSV file to read:");

        File file = new File(fileInput);

        BufferedReader bufRdr;
        bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;

        ArrayList<String[]> arrayOfNumbers = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        //read each line of text file
        while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
            col=0;

            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                //get next token and store it in the array
                // UNSURE WHAT TO PUT HERE
            }
            row++;
        }
```

Then I want to store the data in that list into a multi-dimensional array called `String[][] numbers`.  Any ideas of what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you can initialize your multidim array of Strings you need to know the dimension of it which is analog to your maximum column-size (in case the lines do not have the same amount of 'tokens') and the number of rows which is number of lines you've got.

```
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    String fileInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            "Please enter the path of the CSV file to read:");

    File file = new File(fileInput);

    BufferedReader bufRdr;
    bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = null;

    ArrayList<StringTokenizer> arrayOfNumbers = new ArrayList<StringTokenizer>();

    //read each line of text file
    while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
        arrayOfNumbers.add(st);

        int actColCount = st.countTokens();

        if (col < actColCount) {
             col = actColCount;
        }
    }

    row = arrayOfNumbers.size();
```

now you can iterate over the stored lines and put them into your array. maybe there occure some ArrayOutOfBound Exceptions, didn't went into detail too much. but that should do.

```
    String[][] numbers = new String[row][col];

    for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {

        StringTokenizer st = arrayOfNumbers.get(i);

        int j = 0;
        while(st.hasMoreElements()) {
             numbers[i][j] = st.nextElement();
             j++;
        }
    }
```

please be careful with those fields in the array which are not have a value because there were not enough elements in that line to fill every column/field in that row. this fields return a null.